# Pandas - plot dataframe where each cell is a bar

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have the following dataframe:

```
class   avg         Advanced    Honors  Normal
A       90.00%      4.0         6.0     3.6 
B       85.00%      6.0         9.0     4.5 
C       80.00%      7.0         10.0    7.0 
D       32.00%      7.0         8.0     8.0
```

I made this graph in excel, and need to reproduce it in pandas:

[image]

I've gotten close, but I'm having the most trouble setting each class as its own bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to adding `T`

```
df.drop('avg',1).set_index('class').T.plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

Comment: Never even knew such a function existed. Thanks.